# Intellij IDEA don't recognize Play 2.0 features

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I checked out project from Github, then run `sbt gen-idea` and opened this project in IDEA. One of the project modules uses Play 2.0 Framework.

But IDEA don't recognize symbols specific to Play!. 
I.e. I get following error: `cannot resolve symbol index` in the following statement `views.html.index`.

Same errors on other specific to Play! Framework features, for example I get same error on `routes` variable.

P.S. I have installed `Play 2.0`, `Scala`, `SBT` plugins and also configured Play 2.0 framework root directory (in `Project Settings - Play configuration`)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't use the Play addon from IntelliJ. It's always far quicker and reliable to use command-line in order to compile/generate the different elements including the famous `*.template.scala`, at the origin of your `cannot resolve symbol index` notification.

All you have to do is to run this command-line based on your app's root folder:  `play` then   `compile`. Of course, do not then any `Rebuild project` from IntelliJ, otherwize you'd erase the generated class files from command-line. When dealing with non-managed resources (like templates), just make a `cmd+F9` to compile.

Making sure you output compilation from IntelliJ is configured to map the same folder than your app's `target` folder (what `sbt gen-idea` (although I use `play`then `idea with-sources=yes`) normally auto-configures).

Then your IntelliJ project would not complain any more about some `views.html.index` unresolved.

Of course, if you really want to benefit from your IntelliJ IDE, make sure you have installed the last Play 2.X [plugin](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/getting-started-with-play-20-in-intellij-idea-12/).

Alternatively, create a custom `run`command in IntelliJ in order to take in account SBT compilation.

Comment: Hi Mik, when I use play idea with-sources=yes, somehow, it complains about with-sources not being known: `[error] Not a valid key: with-sources (similar: watch-sources, sources, resources)` Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Did you firstly type `play` command alone, and then `idea with-sources=yes`?

Comment: I tried idea and with-sources as params for the play.bat cmdline. Will try the suggested way, thanks!

Comment: @Jaap That should work. Actually, this command in one step as you tried doesn't work ;)  (I updated my answer to reflect it)

Comment: Since this question is specifically about getting IDEA to work with Play, I think that discouraging the user from using IDEA is not helpful.  Also the user already said the installed the plugins you suggested they install.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Java Play 2.4.x and IntelliJ 15, my colleagues at work kept running into this issue as well. We had the Scala plugin installed (which comes with SBT built in) and all of our dependencies were fine. Turns out the issue arose from the way that they were opening the project (don't ask me why).

**Do:**
File -> New -> Project from Existing Sources...

**Do Not:**
File -> Open

Comment: In IDEA 2016.1, I noticed that after the Scala plugin threw an exception, Intellij silently disabled it.  All future attempts to import/open a Play (sbt based) project failed.  My only clue was that Scala wasn't listed in the left column of language choices in the New Project dialog. I'm not sure if the Scala plugin is flakey or JetBrains is making it flakey.

Comment: For IDEA 2016.1, here are the elaborate instructions for opening a Play/sbt project. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/getting-started-with-sbt.html?